# Your client application uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated

Tags: google-signin, google-authentication

I have a project with **Angular 8** version, using google sign in with a library called **angularx-social-login**.

Lately, I'm getting this in the console:

> "Your client application uses libraries for user authentication or
> authorization that will soon be deprecated..."

I tried implementing the new **@abacritt/angularx-social-login** on an **Angular 13** project and still get the same message.

After doing some reading I understand that on the end of March 2023, this use will not be supported anymore.
Is it true?
If so, I need an advice for how to use "google sign in" with Angular.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here is a repository with a very simple google sign in using Angular and Google Identity, without any other external library, if anybody needs it.

https://github.com/ShemiNechmad/GoogleSignInAngular

Follow the readme.md file for instructions.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of work with updating huge old app